# How can I stop scanning a file once array is full?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am working on a Java project which has a method that reads a file, converts the file elements to objects, and adds them to an array. A maximum of thirty objects can be added to the array. The file I was assigned has about 100 objects in it. Whenever I try to read the file, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30
```

I know what the error means, but I don't know how to stop scanning the file once the array limit has been reached.

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
String skip;

if(count == MAX){
     skip = scanFile.nextLine();
  }
```

Comment: You need to post more of your code. Is there an `else` branch for that `if` where you put things into the array, or would the part that adds items to your array get executed even if that `if` did?

Comment: Is there nothing in the file that you read that tells you the exact size of the data you're meant to receive?

Comment: @Makoto: It's called "end-of-file"

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: In assignments like this, *typically* the first line in the file indicates how many more lines are left to read in.  30 entries as a limit is an extremely arbitrary limit which the OP mentions, so I'd like to know if the limit is artificial (imposed by them), imposed by the data, or imposed by the assignment.

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, and that's why assignments like that are a bit silly because exceedingly few real-life text file formats specify the number of lines. It's good to learn to program without such training wheels.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen:  Not that I disagree, but the "end of file" comment doesn't *help*.  Regardless of the imposition of that constraint, I don't see how it benefits the OP in figuring out their problem, nor us in understanding where the limit came from.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to close the Scanner once you have input a max:

```
 final int MAX = 30;
 int count = 0;

 while(count <= MAX){
     String line = scanner.nextLine();
     //Process the line and add to the array
     myArray[count++] = //whatever
 }
 //close the Scanner
 scanner.close();
```

Also remember that arrays are zero based index.